# How to replace Bodhi Linux with Xubuntu on my dual-boot system?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, xubuntu

I have Windows XP and Bodhi Linux installed on two different partitions and dual boot with Grub.

I want to leave XP untouched and replace Bodhi with Xubuntu 16.04.

Can I simply format the Bodhi partition and install Xubuntu on it like I normally would? Is there anything special I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly - you can format the Bodhi Linux partition and install Xubuntu on this partition. Boot from the Xubuntu installation media, choose the option **Something else** and select the partition where Bodhi Linux was installed as the **target partition** for the Xubuntu operating system. Here is a  comprehensive installation guide : [A Step By Step Guide To Installing Xubuntu Linux](https://www.lifewire.com/guide-to-installing-xubuntu-linux-2202075). There is nothing special to take care of - most important is to choose the **Something else** option, right at the beginning ... to avoid accidental damage of the Windows operating system you want to keep.

Comment: I'm in Xubuntu now :)